# How is isEmpty() different from size() == 0 in Priority Queue

Tags: java, priority-queue

So I'm doing the leetcode question "Top K Frequent Element" and I used priorityQueue for frequency. When I start to poll the numbers and insert into arraylist, somehow the for loop doesn't poll out all the elements in the Queue. Why?

(Say PQ has two elements)

```
    while(!pq.isEmpty()){
        ls.add(pq.poll());
    }

    for(int b = 0; b < pq.size();b++){
        ls.add(pq.poll());
    }
```

Shouldn't these two loops print out the same thing?

I got the correct answer from the while loop while I only got one element from the for loop

Comment: The size decreases on each iteration, so you should not increment `b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference with the second approach is that the value of `b < pq.size()` is *changing* at each iteration, as the number of element decreases when you remove an element: `pq.poll()`. To obtain the same result (assuming that we don't add further elements to the queue while doing the iteration), try this:

```
for (int b = 0, n = pq.size(); b < n; b++) {
    ls.add(pq.poll());
}
```

In the above snippet, we save the size of `pq` exactly *once* at the start of the iteration, to make sure it doesn't change. This will work even better, because it accounts for the case of concurrent insertions/deletions:

```
while (pq.size() > 0) {
    ls.add(pq.poll());
}
```

Comment: Thie first version doesn't work if there are parallel inserti ar deletions. The 'while` loop does.

Comment: @user207421 not OP's situation (it's a leet code question with well-defined inputs), but thanks for pointing it out!